# <section> or <article>, which is contained in which

Tags: html, article

Trying to get my head around the new semantic elements in HTML5.

Does a `<section>` belong inside an `<article>` or is it the other way around? Does it even matter?

I'm looking at re-structuring a wordpress blog.

Comment: The link to the attempted layout does not seem to work.

Comment: @Abizern, could you upload an image to StackOverflow instead of linking off-site to one? The current image your question is about is broken.

Comment: At the time I posted the question, there wasn't the option to do that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#sections):

> The `section` element represents a generic document or application section. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of content, typically with a header and possibly a footer.

and

> The `article` element represents an independent section of a document, page, or site. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, or any other independent item of content.

So I would say both `section` and `article` elements can contain the other element, if appropriate. I think your diagram makes sense, apart from the nested section elements:

> The section element is not a generic container element. When an element is needed for styling purposes or as a convenience for scripting, authors are encouraged to use the div element instead. A general rule is that the section element is appropriate only if the element's contents would be listed explicitly in the document's outline.

Maybe use a `<div>` for the outer one?

Answer (score 3):

I would use div for the outer one, and div for the inner one, unless you have a heading directly inside the inner section.

See http://html5doctor.com/the-section-element for more info.

Answer (score 1):

IMOO, it should be simple, as simple as what normal people will take it for granted. If a simple tag name confuses people, it is a fail. For me:

- An `<article>` *is an article*. People share articles. When you say something is an article, I'll expect it should have a **title**, and maybe a little summary as well, so I can decide to read it or not. If it is interesting, I will share it to my friends. It's self-contained.
- A `<section>` *is a section*. It is **a part** of related things.  Basically, you will need other sections to get the whole picture.

***Why you put a `<section>` inside the `<body>`?*** Oh because it's part of the body; part of my website. I'm going to put my articles inside this part.

***Why you put a `<section>` inside a `<section>`?*** Because it's part of *that* section.