# Difference between Section vs Article elements in HTML

Tags: html

I have a page made up of various "sections" like videos, a newsfeed etc.. I am a bit confused how to represent these with HTML. Currently I have them as HTML `<section>`s, but on further inspection it looks they the more correct tag would be `<article>`. Could anyone shed some light on this for me?

None of these things are blog posts or "documents" in the true sense of the word so it's kind of hard to see which element to apply.

Answer (score 237, accepted):

In the [W3 wiki page about structuring HTML5](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_structural_elements#Enter_HTML5_structural_elements), it says:

> **`<section>`**: Used to either group different articles into different purposes or
>   subjects, or to define the different sections of a single article.

And then displays [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTOXa.jpg) that I cleaned up:

[image]

It also describes how to use the `<article>` tag (from same W3 link above):

> `<article>` is related to `<section>`, but is distinctly different.
>   Whereas `<section>` is for grouping distinct sections of content or
>   functionality, `<article>` is for containing related individual
>   standalone pieces of content, such as individual blog posts, videos,
>   images or news items. Think of it this way - if you have a number of
>   items of content, each of which would be suitable for reading on their
>   own, and would make sense to syndicate as separate items in an RSS
>   feed, then `<article>` is suitable for marking them up.
>
> In our example, `<section id="main">` contains blog entries. Each blog
>   entry would be suitable for syndicating as an item in an RSS feed, and
>   would make sense when read on its own, out of context, therefore
>   `<article>` is perfect for them:

```
<section id="main">
    <article>
      <!-- first blog post -->
    </article>

    <article>
      <!-- second blog post  -->
    </article>

    <article>
      <!-- third blog post -->
    </article>
</section>
```

> Simple huh? Be aware though that you can also nest sections inside
>   articles, where it makes sense to do so. For example, if each one of
>   these blog posts has a consistent structure of distinct sections, then
>   you could put sections inside your articles as well. It could look
>   something like this:

```
<article>
  <section id="introduction">
  </section>

  <section id="content">
  </section>

  <section id="summary">
  </section>
</article>
```

Comment: Additionally: <main> can be used to wrap the elements between the header and footer (blue blocks from the image). <figure> wraps images within the articles or sections.

Comment: You should update the pic with the section in articles.

Comment: I feel like this war between article and section will go one now because of the confusion. But Justin Im 100% on board your use of section over article as section applies to parts of documents (as you have shown) where article is stand-alone, independent content INSIDE the document (and thus its sections). Semantically the term "section" just makes more sense as a replacement for the old div sections anyway. Good job!

Comment: You can also use <header> and <footer> inside the <article> if you need something more specific than <section>

Comment: It's worth noting that each `article` and `section` [should be identified by heading (h1-h6)](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Usage/Headings/Missing).

Comment: Thank you for this answer! HTML5 also has a `<main>`  tag. Should the `<main>` tag wrap the whole page (`header`, `nav`, all `section`s, `aside`s and `footer`, i.e. all the green and blue blocks) or should it only wrap the `section`s and maybe the `aside`s tag (only the blue blocks)? Thank you!

Comment: I do wonder. Assuming one can't position a search bar inside the <header>, only inside the <main>. Can that search bar be inside a <section> tag?. I know that <section> tag requires headers, and so, not sure if to position it inside a simple <div> with no meaning or inside a <section>. Also, didn't quite see any topic regarding which tag is best for positioning a search bar. Most say <header>, but if that is not an option - No one talks about alternative

Answer (score 139):

Sounds like you should wrap each of the "sections" (as you call them) in `<article>` tags and entries in the article in `<section>` tags.

The [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-section-element) says (Section):

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or
>   application. A section, in this context, is a thematic grouping of
>   content, typically with a heading. [...]
>
> > Examples of sections would be chapters, the various tabbed pages in
> >     a tabbed dialog box, or the numbered sections of a thesis. A Web
> >     site's home page could be split into sections for an introduction,
> >     news items, and contact information.
>
> **Note**: Authors are encouraged to use the article element instead of the
>   section element when it would make sense to syndicate the contents of
>   the element.

And for [Article](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-article-element)

> The article element represents a self-contained composition in a
>   document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle,
>   independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This
>   could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry,
>   a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any
>   other independent item of content.

I think what you call "sections" in the OP fit the definition of article as I can see them being *independently distributable or reusable*.

**Update:** Some minor text changes for `article` in the [latest editors draft for HTML 5.1](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-article-element) (changes in italic):

> The article element represents a *complete, or* self-contained,
>   composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in
>   principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in
>   syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper
>   article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget
>   or gadget, or any other independent item of content.

Also, discussion on the Public HTML mailing list about `article` in [January](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2013Jan/0109.html) and [February](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2013Feb/0002.html) of 2013.

Comment: while searching on the web, i came across a legal document that read `Article 1, Section 2, Clause 3`. I hope that will help me remember the logic.

Comment: I disagree to an extent, but I also believe they could be switched depending on the context. Reading the spec descriptions suggests to me that it should be the other way around if an `article` acts as a "widget". `section`: "thematic grouping" and "section of a document". `article`: "self-contained" and "widget". Consider a homepage example like http://codepen.io/anon/pen/iDEwf

Comment: Why do they say that a *single* forum post makes an article? A forum post is not complete without the rest of the thread imho.

Comment: I agree with @masterxilo's line of thinking.  We need to ask, when does it "make sense to syndicate the contents of the element"?  I've come across this rubric many times and I've concluded that it begs the question (of "when to use article").

Comment: This is backwards. W3C clearly state that `section` is a thematic grouping of content, and `article` is a stand-alone element (ie. which could be grouped into a theme). Think of it like a newspaper: You will find many articles in each section. Film review articles in the Entertainment section, for example.

Comment: Agreeing with @Chuck here. In my book this answer has it completely backwards. [Justin's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24764861/151509) is way more fitting. But oh well, guess the spec leaves a lot of room for interpretation. Not sure though if this a bad or good thing.

Comment: @maryisdead, I think the main takeaway is that content in an article element should stand on its own. I think that part is clear from the spec. I may have misinterpreted the OP's description of the content but hopefully the pointers to the spec that are linked are helpful to others trying to decide how to markup their content.

Comment: @steveax From what I get, OP meant having a list of videos, a list of news article etc. If OP was talking about applying `<section>` or `<article>` to single items of those, you are, of course, correct.

Answer (score 48):

I'd use `<article>` for a text block that is totally unrelated to the other blocks on the page.
`<section>`, on the other hand, would be a divider to separate a document which have are related to each other.

Now, I'm not sure what you have in your videos, news feed etc, but here's an example (there's no REAL right or wrong, just a guideline of how I use these tags):

```
<article>
    <h1>People</h1>
    <p>text about people</p>
    <section>
        <h1>fat people</h1>
        <p>text about fat people</p>
    </section>
    <section>
        <h1>skinny people</p>
        <p>text about skinny people</p>
    </section>
</article>
<article>
    <h1>Cars</h1>
    <p>text about cars</p>
    <section>
        <h1>Fast Cars</h1>
        <p>text about fast cars</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

As you can see, the sections are still relevant to each other, but as long as they're inside a block that groups them. Sections DON'T have to be inside articles. They can be in the body of a document, but I use sections in the body, when the whole document is one article.

e.g.

```
<body>
    <h1>Cars</h1>
    <p>text about cars</p>
    <section>
        <h1>Fast Cars</h1>
        <p>text about fast cars</p>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: `I'd use <article> for a text block that is totally unrelated to the other blocks on the page.` I know you wrote this back in 2011, but, isn't this what the `<aside>` tag is for?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions No. `> The <aside> HTML element represents a portion of a document whose content is only indirectly related to the document's main content. Asides are frequently presented as sidebars or call-out boxes.`

Answer (score 37):

The flowchart below can be of help when choosing one of the various semantic HTML5 elements:

> [image]

[Image](https://html5doctor.com/downloads/h5d-sectioning-flowchart.png) courtesy of @riddle & @boblet [HTML5 Doctor](https://html5doctor.com/resources/)

Answer (score 24):

I like to stick with the standard meaning of the words used: An `article` would apply to, well, articles. I would define blog posts, documents, and news articles as `articles`. Sections on the other hand, would refer to layout/ux items: sidebar, header, footer would be sections. However this is all my own personal interpretation -- as you pointed out, the specification for these elements are not well defined.

Supporting this, the [w3c](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/article) defines an `article` element as a section of content that can independently stand on its own. A blog post could stand on it's own as a valuable and consumable item of content. However, a header would not.

[Here](http://visitmix.com/writings/article-vs-section-weve-finally-gone-mad) is an interesting article about one mans madness in trying to differenciate between the two new elements. The basic point of the article, that I also feel is correct, is to try and use what ever element you feel best actually represents what it contains.

> What’s more problematic is that article and section are so very
>   similar. All that separates them is the word “self-contained”.
>   Deciding which element to use would be easy if there were some hard
>   and fast rules. Instead, it’s a matter of interpretation. You can have
>   multiple articles within a section, you can have multiple sections
>   within and article, you can nest sections within sections and articles
>   within sections. It’s up to you to decide which element is the most
>   semantically appropriate in any given situation.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789692/section-or-article-which-is-contained-in-which/1789745#1789745) is a very good answer to the same question here on SO

Answer (score 8):

**Section**

- Use this for defining a section of your layout. It could be `mid`,`left`,`right`
  ,etc..
- This has a meaning of connection with some other element, put simply, it's DEPENDENT.

**Article**

- Use this where you have independent content which make sense on its own .
- Article has its own complete meaning.

Answer (score 4):

A section is basically a wrapper for `h1` (or other `h` tags) and the content that corresponds to this. An `article` is essentially a document within your document that is repeated or paginated...like each blog post on your document can be an article, or each comment on your document can be an article.

Answer (score 2):

also, for syndicated content "Authors are encouraged to use the article element instead of the section element when it would make sense to syndicate the contents of the element."

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation is:
I think of YouTube it has a comment-section, and inside the comment-section there are multiple articles (in this case comments).

So a section is like a div-container that holds articles.

Answer (score 0):

Markup the sections of your webpage using `<section>` elements. Articles lend themselves to the schema.org microdata vocabulary as a `CreativeWork` subtype or are indicated for use as widget containers.

#### `<article>`

> The article element represents a complete, or self-contained, composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is, in principle, independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content..
> [source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element)

The published [example use cases](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#article-example) are (1) widget containers and (2) blog posts.

It is noted that

> Authors are encouraged to use the article element instead of the
> section element when it would make sense to syndicate the contents of
> the element. [source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element:the-article-element)

#### `<section>`

> The section element represents a generic section of a document or
> application.
> [source](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element)