# Placing sections in divs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, semantic-markup

I am writing guidelines in two columns. It came across whether placing sections inside divs is a good practice.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <section> 
     <h5>Heading 1</h5>
     <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </section><!-- Content 1 -->                             
  <section> 
     <h5>Heading 2</h5>
     <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  </section><!-- Content 2 -->  
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<div>` tags are generic tags usually used for styling, as in Bootstrap like in your example. You could do something like this to have more semantically right HTML5:

```
<article class="col-md-6">
  <section> 
     <h5>Heading 1</h5>
     <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </section><!-- Content 1 -->                             
  <section> 
     <h5>Heading 2</h5>
     <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  </section><!-- Content 2 -->  
</article>
```

or with keeping the `div` in your markup, just put your initial code in `article` tag, where `div` will be used for styling purpose:

```
<article>
 <div class="col-md-6">
  <section> 
     <h5>Heading 1</h5>
     <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </section><!-- Content 1 -->                             
  <section> 
     <h5>Heading 2</h5>
     <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  </section><!-- Content 2 -->  
 </div>
</article>
```

Comment: i'm really not sure of this answer, refering [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549561/section-vs-article-html5) or [this](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp).

Answer (score -1):

i think a better way to do this is to use section instead div and then article instead section

```
<section class="col-md-6">
  <article> 
     <h5>Heading 1</h5>
     <p>Paragraph 1</p>
  </article><!-- Content 1 -->                             
  <article> 
     <h5>Heading 2</h5>
     <p>Paragraph 2</p>
  </article><!-- Content 2 -->  
</section>
```

Comment: Regarless to a previous post "<article> is related to <section>, but is distinctly different. Whereas <section> is for grouping distinct sections of content or functionality, <article> is for containing related individual standalone pieces of content, such as individual blog posts, videos, images or news items.". Could read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549561/section-vs-article-html5);